# Change default location for generating controllers in Workbench/Package Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am currently trying to make it easier for my team and I to generate controllers for our packages. I know I can use php artisan controller:make --path, but I would rather use the --package or --bench command instead.

Basically, I have moved all my folders from src to src/Vendor/Package, including my controllers/ If I were to use php artisan controller:make --bench vendor/package Controller, then it generates it inside src/controllers which I don't want it to do.

Whenever I generate a controller this way, I want it to default to src/Vendor/Package and would like to know the best way of changing the location.

I would be grateful for any help on this one as I have searched around and found nothing on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install JeffreyWay Generators. Generators allowes you to pass --path --bench flag etc

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators